# Solr: search on words and their full nGrams

Tags: apache, solr

I have following features in 2 documents:

```
1: name: "John Oliver W Clane"
2: name: "John Oliver Wayne"
```

If a search query is `q=john`, 1 and 2 should surface. if query is `q=john oli`, 1 and 2 should surface. But if query is `q=wayne`only 2 should surface. And if query is `q=oliver w` both 1 and 2 should surface.

Basically, all the words in the name should be searched from edge.
How do I configure this in solr?

Note: `name` is indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below fieldType for you field `name`.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="25"/>
</analyzer>
```

Input String: `"John Oliver W Clane"`

Tokenizer to Filter: `"John Oliver W Clane"`

Output Tokens :

```
"John", "John ", "John O", "John Ol", "John Oli", "John Oli", "John Oliv", "John Olive", "John Oliver", "John Oliver ", "John Oliver W", "John Oliver W "
, "John Oliver W C", "John Oliver W Cl", "John Oliver W Cla", "John Oliver W Clan", "John Oliver W Clane".
```

There is another filter you can try the same .

```
<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="25"/>
```

You can read more about the analyzers and filters here.[Solr analyzers and filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions)

Comment: Thanks. I am checking out these solutions.